# SQL - Same table - Having c2.Country <> c.Country - need to understand

Tags: sql

I tried the following SQL query and did not understand how last part in the parenthesis

```
SELECT COUNT(c2.CustomerID) 
FROM Customers AS c2 
GROUP BY c2.Country 
HAVING c2.Country <> c.Country
```

works.

```
SELECT COUNT(c.CustomerID) AS cnt, c.Country
FROM Customers c
GROUP BY c.Country
HAVING cnt NOT IN (SELECT COUNT(c2.CustomerID) 
                   FROM Customers AS c2 
                   GROUP BY c2.Country 
                   HAVING c2.Country <> c.Country);
```

The first three lines give me country name and count of their customer id.

For example:

```
Argentina 3
Belgium   3
Brazil    9
IRAN      2
Turkey    2
```

The last part

```
SELECT COUNT(c2.CustomerID) 
FROM Customers AS c2 
GROUP BY c2.Country 
HAVING c2.Country <> c.Country
```

only returns count customer id of country for which there is other countries with the same number of count. How does this work?

For example:

```
3
2
```

and don't give 9 for the brazil.

I don't really understand the second condition of the HAVING query works: Having c2.Country <> c.Country. I know what c2.Country <> c.Country means. I don't understand how the bold line works.

When The query in the parenthesis is  linked to the original query with a "HAVING NOT IN" which essentially compares the values from the first part of the query and the values from the second (Argentina 3, Belgium 3, IRAN 2, Turkey 2) and will return all rows that are not present in the second query, which is Brazil 9.

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (Perhaps MySQL?) Anyway, if that query works, it's still a bit "odd", and probably far from optimal.

Comment: Kindly mention which rdbms you are using

Comment: I tried in on MySQL and Postgresql

Comment: It's basically looking for countries which have unique counts.  Naturally, we don't want to consider the same county (inner country vs outer country) in the comparison, since that count will always match and the result will always be empty.  Another approach would simply be to aggregate twice (several ways to do that), first by country and then by count, returning only those results `HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT cnt) = 1`.  In that case, `SELECT cnt, MIN(country) ...` would be that one country for each `cnt`.

Comment: Adjust... The above should be `COUNT(DISTINCT Country) = 1`... See: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=ebea311123acc17c9aa7cd9c98ed343d

Comment: I think there's a misunderstanding here.  The second results you showed is not generated by any SQL you showed in the question.  Can you clarify what you executed to produce that second result?  The second `expression` has correlated/dependent behavior.  It can `NOT` be run independently.

Comment: Yes. The SQL at the end gives me Brazil 9. The second expression should give the (Argentina 3, Belgium 3, IRAN 2, Turkey 2 I mean (3, 2)) so at the end we take only Brazil 9.

Comment: It does not.  It's invalid SQL, alone.  It can not be run, with that outer reference, which can not be resolved.  Show the entire SQL that you ran.  `c.Country` does not exist.

Comment: Ok. I imagine The expression should give me (2, 3).  when it is linked to the otter through "HAVING NOT IN", the sql at the end give me brazil 9

Comment: That's correct, as expected.

Comment: My question is that how expression gives me 3 and 2?

Comment: @Mohi `IT DOES NOT`, since that expression is invalid SQL.  Use my fiddle to show the actual SQL you ran.  Add your SQL, run the fiddle, then post the new URL here for review.  https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=ebea311123acc17c9aa7cd9c98ed343d   Are you trying to ask why the expression causes the 2 and 3 counts to be eliminated from the result?

Comment: I checked the fiddle you put here. how the expression filter the result and at the end we get only brazil 9.

Comment: If you would like, I can add an answer which steps through the execution of the SQL.  I think that's what you're asking now.

Comment: Yes. Much appreciated.

Comment: Also: `HAVING` should **only** be applied to **aggregated** columns - e.g. `HAVING COUNT(*) > 50` or something like that - it should **NOT** be used as in your case - these conditions go directly against columns - this should be handled by a `WHERE` clause - not a `HAVING` clause ...

Comment: It's acceptable in this case due to the outer group by clause: `GROUP BY c.Country` ... which makes the reference `c.Country` functionally dependent on those terms.  It's the same reason we can use the expression `c.Country` in the outer `SELECT` list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=ebea311123acc17c9aa7cd9c98ed343d)

**Given:**

```
CREATE TABLE Customers (
     CustomerID int PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT
   , Country VARCHAR(20)
);

INSERT INTO Customers (Country) VALUES
    ('Argentina')
  , ('Argentina')
  , ('Argentina')
  , ('Belgium')
  , ('Belgium')
  , ('Belgium')
  , ('Brazil')
  , ('Brazil')
  , ('Brazil')
  , ('Brazil')
  , ('Brazil')
  , ('Brazil')
  , ('Brazil')
  , ('Brazil')
  , ('Brazil')
  , ('IRAN')
  , ('IRAN')
  , ('Turkey')
  , ('Turkey')
;
```

**and the SQL:**

```
SELECT COUNT(c.CustomerID) as cnt, c.Country
  FROM Customers c
 GROUP BY c.Country
Having cnt NOT IN (SELECT COUNT(c2.CustomerID) FROM Customers AS c2 GROUP BY c2.Country Having c2.Country <> c.Country)
;
```

The above SQL has `dependent / correlated` behavior, where the subquery has a reference to the outer row (`c.Country`).

Functionally, that means we execute the subquery for each row generated by the outer `GROUP BY` clause.

This also means we have to be careful to only reference the outer row with expressions that are functionally dependent on the outer `GROUP BY` terms.

**First,** let's look at the entire result of the outer `GROUP BY` logic (without the `HAVING` logic):

| Country | cnt |
| --- | --- |
| Argentina | 3 |
| Belgium | 3 |
| Brazil | 9 |
| IRAN | 2 |
| Turkey | 2 |

Let's take just one outer row as an example:

Country = 'IRAN', cnt = 2

When we execute the subquery for this row, we effectively do this:

```
(SELECT COUNT(c2.CustomerID) FROM Customers AS c2 GROUP BY c2.Country Having c2.Country <> 'IRAN')
```

This produces a list of (only selecting the cnt):

| Country | cnt |
| --- | --- |
| Argentina | 3 |
| Belgium | 3 |
| Brazil | 9 |
| Turkey | 2 |

But without 'IRAN' due to the `HAVING` clause: `Having c2.Country <> c.Country`

The list of `cnt` produced is: 3, 3, 9, 2

Now, since the outer row is associated with `cnt = 2`, the `NOT IN` clause eliminates that outer row from the final result.

The same thing happens to Turkey, Argentina and Belgium, as we process those outer rows.

The only remaining outer row is: Brazil with `cnt = 9`

Let me know if you need more information.

Comment: Thank you! Much appreciated!

Comment: @Mohi If this helps, don't forget to note that by `accepting` or at least `upvoting` the answer.  If you need more detail, just let me know.

Comment: I have accepted the answer. The answer is something I looking for.

Answer (score 0):

The <> is a not equals operator which will return any countries with a customer ID count that is not equal to another country (in this instance Brazil 9). This query in the parenthesis is then linked to the original query with a "HAVING NOT IN" which essentially compares the values from the first part of the query and the values from your second (Brazil 9) and will return all rows that are not present in the second query - the one in your parenthesis. If there was another country with a customer ID count of 9 then Brazil would appear in your final results.

I do agree with @jarlh though that this query is rather odd and likely not fully optimal.

Comment: The values of the second query is (Argentina 3, Belgium 3, IRAN 2, Turkey 2). When these values inked to the original query with a "HAVING NOT IN", it gives me (Brazil 9). I don;'t understand how the second query gives me (Argentina 3, Belgium 3, IRAN 2, Turkey 2).

Comment: @Mohi It doesn't.  You need to edit the question and provide the SQL you actually ran.  The second `expression` is not valid, alone.  It refers to the outer row, which doesn't exist unless you also run that portion of the SQL too.  In that case, the result you showed would not be generated.

Comment: @Mohi the correct SQL had not been provided on the question when I posted this attempted answer. As Jon Armstrong says the second query is not valid by itself because it references the outer query which is not executed if it is ran in isolation.

Answer (score 0):

First things first, your query should return the count first then the name of the country. `SELECT COUNT(c.CustomerID) as cnt, c.Country` not the vice versa. Secondly, `<>` returns the rows where two columns are not equal to each other, which in this case is the country in the outer query does not equal to the country in the inner query.

Comment: Here, the tables in the outer and inner query are the same. I don't expect the country in the outer query does not equal to the country in the inner query.

Comment: @Mohi The `c.Country <> c2.Country` guarantees we never compare the same country between the outer and inner rows.  This is called `dependent` or `correlated` behavior.

Comment: In the case of count number how it only gives 3 and 2, and not 9.